# Multiple menubars with external monitors

Tags: high-sierra, menu-bar

How can the menubar (with the Apple icon, active program name, and options. like File, Edit, View, History) be displayed on each monitor at the same time?

Update:
In the same desktop Space.

Comment: I have two external monitors and there's a menu bar on each one.  They're different, but they're there.  Can you expand on exactly what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @Allan The little black bar with the apple icon, active program name, and options. Like File, Edit, View, History... I'd like it at the top of each monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it by separating the two monitors into separate Spaces - System Prefs > Mission Control.

Personally, I wouldn't, the change to your working method is too great. I'd live with one menu bar, but it's your call.

[image]

Comment: You're right. This works, but switching to separate Spaces is too disruptive.

Comment: I agree. Many people seem to like this workflow, but I really, really don't.